# kvm exiting hardware virtualization

Tags: shutdown, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, reboot

I used to encounter this error when I want to turn off or reboot my system.

Comment: The actual error is missing in your post... Please also add details which Ubuntu release you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many efforts, I was able to solve this problem with the below method

1-

```
sudo rmmod kvm_intel
```

2-

```
sudo rmmod kvm
```

3-

```
sudo apt install libvirt-daemon-system
```

4-

```
sudo systemctl start libvirtd
```

5-

```
sudo systemctl enable libvirtd
```

6-

```
sudo systemctl restart libvirtd
```

7-And finally log out of Ubuntu and log in again

I hope this will solve your problem